# JAVA, giving an instance that is still null attributes

Tags: java, data-structures, nullpointerexception, avl-tree

I am implementing an AvlTree. In the Avl tree i want to compare heights of Vertices for adjusting the Avl if there are violations (RR,LR,RL,LL). 
So i have AvlNode class which has a AvlNode.getHeight() method.
But e.g when i have this:
AvlNode.getRightNode().getHeight() is an error since it has no right node at that moment. Obviously this could be fixed with some null checks. But i want my AvlNode class to give null instances the height of 0 without performing these checks.
I thought about using a FACADE to wrap the AvlNode class, and whenever a getHeight method is called for a null instance it returns 0. 
Is there a better way to achieve this goal?

Comment: How about creating a constructor with default values and assign real values while parsing

Answer (score 0):

I think you could wrapper it with
AvlNode.getRightNodeHeight()

Comment: Thanks. But how can i wrap getHeight with getRightNode? I nee getHeight to return 0 if getRightNode is null